# Gmail style dropdown select using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Upon clicking the 'Gmail' (with arrow next to it), menu options such as 'Contacts', 'Tasks' show up.

Is there a similar component in bootstrap? or any other plugin to achieve the same?

Comment: Show us your work. In this way, we can not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this? http://cdpn.io/BqHfm

It's based on the [Bootstrap Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-examples)

```
<div class="dropdown">

 <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Mail <span class="caret"></span></a>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="#">Mail</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Good luck!